# what is the length of this variable?

Tags: sas

This is the code:

```
data work.accounting;
   set work.department;
   length jobcode $ 12;
run;
```

The work.department sas data set contains a variable named JOBCODE with a length of 5. Which one of the following is the length of the variable JOBCODE in the output data set?
The right answer is 5. But I think it should be 12, right? Could anyone explain to me the reason of it? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the length,we must use the **LENGTH statement as the very first statement in the DATA STEP** ,but  the **position will be changed at the same time**. In your code the LENGTH statement has no effect on the length of JOBCODE variable because of this

Comment: what do you mean, "the position will be changed at the same time"?

Comment: @Lucy-  Lets say your dataset has 3 variables JobName, JobCode and JobType in that particular order. If you change the length of JobCode by placing the length statement right after the DATA step then the order of the variables will change to JobCode, JobName , JobType. Always a length statement (or for that matter a RETAIN statement) right after a DATA statement changes the order in which they are placed in the data

Comment: The variable position/order in the data set changed, ie column order changes.

Comment: @Vishant, so, suppose the dataset has 3 variables JobName, JobCode, and JobType in this particular order. If I change the length of JobType by placing the length statement right after the DATA step, then the order of the variables will be changed into JobType, JobName, and JobCode, is it right?

Comment: @Lucy -  Yes! you are right, that's the way it works :)

Answer (score 1):

SAS will define the type and length of a variable as soon as it can. Since `JOBCODE` exists in the dataset being referenced by the `SET` statement it will be defined to match how it is defined in the dataset.  By the time the compiler sees the `LENGTH` statement the variable's type and length are already defined. SAS will print a warning message in the log that the length of the variable has already been set.